# Parity of a number (Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So I'm trying to separate an octet by parity and I don't quite understand how the conditional jumps work(I tried it separately and I don't understand how it works it)

Here is what I came up with:

```
bits 32
global start
extern exit,printf
import exit msvcrt.dll
import printf msvcrt.dll

segment data use32 class=data

    s db '1', '2', '3', '4','5','7','8','9' ; declararea sirului initial s
l   equ $-s ; stabilirea lungimea sirului initial l
    d1 times l db 0
    d2 times 1 db 0
format db "%s", 0

segment code use32 class=code

start:
mov ecx, l
    mov esi, 0
    jecxz Sfarsit
Repeta:
    ;loop so it gets all the elements from s
mov al, [s+esi]
    mov bl,al
    sub bl,'0'
    cmp bl,2; if is even adds it to d1
    JP et2
    mov [d1+esi], al
inc esi
et2:
    mov bl,al
    sub bl,'0'
    cmp bl,2; if is odd adds it to d2
    JP et1
    mov [d2+esi], al
    inc esi
et1:
    loop Repeta
Sfarsit: ;terminarea programului
    ;Daca dorim si afisarea sirului d, avem urmatoarele:
    push dword d1 ; punem parametrii pe stiva de la dreapta la stanga
    push dword format
    call [printf] ;apelam functia printf
    add esp, 4 * 2 ; eliberam parametrii de pe stiva
    ; exit(0)
    push dword d2 ; punem parametrii pe stiva de la dreapta la stanga
    push dword format
    call [printf] ;apelam functia printf
    add esp, 4 * 2 ; eliberam parametrii de pe stiva
    ; exit(0)
    push dword 0 ; push the parameter for exit onto the stack
    call [exit] ; call exit to terminate the program
```

I think the problem is the `JP` but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Can you describe what your code should do and what it does instead of what it should do?

Comment: I added some comments

Comment: Parity is not about whether a number is even or odd, and you certainly don't test that with a `cmp bl, 2`. Something along the lines of `test bl, 1; jz even` should work better. Also, you have duplicated code, at `et2` you no longer need to test. Furthermore, the execution falls through into `et2` you probably want a jump there.

Comment: @Skillwalker The comments do not address the question I asked you. What do you expect the program to do and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
    cmp bl,2; if is even adds it to d1
    JP et2
```

`cmp` in this case does `temp = bl - 2` and throws away the result, but keeps the flags affected (same way as `sub bl,2` would affect them).

And `jp` is "jump parity", which means it will jump when PF=1, it has also alias `jpe` or "jump when even".

But that's about bit-parity of the low 8 bits of result, i.e. it counts number of "1" values in low 8 bits of result and sets PF=1 when there's even number of ones. As you use only 8 bits in the arithmetic flag setting instruction (`cmp`), the whole result is used to calculate PF, but if you would do for example `cmp ebx,2`, it would have same result in PF, as only 8 bits of result are used to count ones.

In your case the values processed (in binary):

```
bl          temp (low 8b)    PF
0001 (1)    11111111 (-1)    1 (8 mod 2 = 0)
0010 (2)    00000000 (0)     1 (0 mod 2 = 0)
0011 (3)    00000001 (1)     0 (1 mod 2 = 1)
0100 (4)    00000010 (2)     0 (1 mod 2 = 1)
0101 (5)    00000011 (3)     1 (2 mod 2 = 0)
0111 (7)    00000101 (5)     1 (2 mod 2 = 0)
1000 (8)    00000110 (6)     1 (2 mod 2 = 0)
1001 (9)    00000111 (7)     0 (3 mod 2 = 1)
```

So `bl` values 1, 2, 5, 7, 8 will take `jp` jump.

If you want to test `bl` if the value is even (`bl mod 2 = 0`), then you need:

```
    test bl,1           ; mask-out all bit except the lowest one
    jz   even_value     ; when lowest bit is zero, value is even
```

The `test` instruction does `temp = bl AND 00000001`, and throws away result (temp), keeps only flags. Binary values are even, when their lowest digit (bit) is zero, because that one has value 2<sup>0</sup> = 1, so that's the one which makes odd values possible. When you bit-wise mask the original value against 00000001, you keep only the lowest bit, so `jz` "jump zero" will happen when that lowest bit was zero -> value was even.

---

also probably some more problems you will encounter:

```
d1 times l db 0
d2 times 1 db 0    ; probably "times l db 0" meant?
```

And you wanted to split values into `d1 / d2` when they are even odd?
But you are using the same index `esi`, so if you will fix your test, and your "store value into" logic, you will split the values into two arrays:

```
d1:    '1', 0, '3', 0, '5', '7', 0, '9'
d2:    0, '2', 0, '4', 0, 0, '8', 0
```

And your current code will store only values which set PF=0, but into both arrays, as both your branches have identical calculation.

To get the arrays as described above (with odd/even values, on their original index) you can do:

```
    mov   edi,d1        ; target array ptr for odd values
    mov   edx,d2        ; target array ptr for even values
    test  al,1          ; test if al has even value
      ; you can test directly the ASCII digit, '0' = 0x30 = even
    cmovz edi,edx       ; edi = target array ptr
    mov   [edi+esi],al  ; store AL into desired array
```

... and I will rather not even check code below that loop, but I think you should execute it in debugger, and single-step over each instruction to see, what it does (very likely NOT, what you did want/expect).