# intel assembly TEST PF flag operation

Tags: assembly, flags, operation, parity

I'm was doing a manual operation with `TEST` `(Parity flag operation)`, the problem it's that i can't get the right result, consider this:

`ax = 256 = 0000 0001 0000 0000`

so if i do:

`test ah, 0x44`

the `PF` flag operation should be:

`0000 0000 =` `0000 0001` `&` `0100 0100`

`PF = 0000 0000 XNOR 0000 0000`

`PF = 1111 1111`?

I've followed the intel reference, according to this:

[image]

the question it's what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you are trying to set or reset PF flag you can do that with `lahf instruction` have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335653/how-to-check-if-the-cf-flag-is-1-in-emu8086/47373859#47373859

Comment: @Doda  No, I want to do the formula manually, the problem it's that i'm not getting the same result than the program operation...

Comment: You're reading the reference incorrectly. First, the parameter is `TEMP[0:7]` but you are using `TEMP[15:8]`. Second, `BitwiseXNOR` has only one parameter, so it's not clear why you are calculating `0000 0000 XNOR 0000 0000` (especially since the result has 8 bits, but PF is only one bit). What `BitwiseXNOR` means is to XOR all the bits together, and then negate the result.

Comment: I don't understand Are you trying to set/reset PF flag ?

Comment: @Raymond Chen Can you post a example or link example please? i can't find a operation done like example, and you mean `bit0 to bit7 xorged and then negated?` something like this `~(0^0^0^0^0^0^0)`?

Comment: @Doda No. just i want to do the operation manually...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BitwiseXNOR` is a *horizontal* XNOR of the bits, producing a single bit.  Remember that PF is only 1 bit wide (a flag in EFLAGS), so it makes no sense to write `PF=1111 1111`.

---

It's the same parity calculation as always for instructions that "set flags according to the result", except that it's done on `test`'s internal temporary result.  (And as always, on the low 8 bits of it, regardless of operand size).

PF = 0 if the number of set bits is odd, PF = 1 if the number of set bits is even.  So yes, the expression you posted in comments, `~(0^0^0^0^0^0^0^0)` is correct.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_flag
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit points out that parity is also the inverted (sum mod 2) of all the bits.  (Because `XOR` is add-without-carry).  Parity of an integer wider than 8 bits can be computed with `popcnt eax, eax` / `not eax` / `and eax, 1`.  (Or use BMI `andn eax, eax, ecx` with `ecx=1` set outside a loop to do the not-and part in one instruction.)  Or just use the inverted parity value, where 1 = odd parity.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372252/parity-of-a-number-assembly/47372485#47372485) has several examples of how PF is set from the horizontal-XOR of the bits in a result.  In your case, the 8 bits are the AND result that `test` internally generates.

Comment: yes, i had a bad logic about `BitwiseXNOR(Temporary[0:7]);` because that i'm was doing wrong... thank you...